# How to generate hash password and store it in database in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I want to create new user and save into user table in my data base
i act as follows:

```
create: function(req,res,next){
    bcrypt.hash(req.param('password'),10,function (err, hashed) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("4");
          return res.serverError({'err': 'hash Error!'});
        } else{
                User.create({
                  username: req.param('username'),
                  password: hashed,
                  type: req.param('type')
                },function (err, created_user) {
                      if (err) {
                        err = validator(User, err);
                        return res.json({'status': false, 'errors': err.Errors});
                      }
                      return res.json({'status': true, 'result': created_user});
                }
      );
            }

    }
}
```

My User Model is:

```
module.exports = {
```

attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    },

```
password: {
  type: 'string',
  required: true
},

type: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'integer'
},

last_x_map: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'float'
},

last_y_map: {
  type: 'number',
  columnType: 'float'
},

places :{
  collection: 'place',
  via: 'user_owner'
},

},
validationMessages: {

username:{
  required: '...',
  alphanumericdashed: '...',
  unique: '...'
},

password: {
  required: '...'
}

},
```

But it always return false and do not any thing.

Where is the problem?
Or what do you recommend for this?
thanks a lot.

Comment: where does it return to false? Does it print any error?

Comment: i use postman to send request. no does not print any error, just in postman show as result: {"status": false}

Comment: @dnp1204 What do you suggest to do this? Very important please help me

Comment: It seems you code fails on User create method. Could you post your User model definition?

Comment: Yes, I'm sending

Comment: @Luiz Carraro i edited my question

Comment: Could you `console.log` the `err` ?

Comment: @Hamza Fatmi  Nothing is displayed in console. when i create new user  whit out hashing password by bcrypt it works very good, But when i use create new user codes into bcrypt I'm having trouble!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @mascm what I meant to say was since your code returns { status : false } then `err` is true , I asked you to put a `console.log(err)` after `if(err)` to output the `err` to the console.

Comment: Please post how you are requesting the endpoint.

Comment: What I see here as a code should work - nothing wrong. However my guess is you already have a record with the same username in your DB, and your username is unique. So using Postman with the same username every time will give an error. Just consider this, I may be wrong though. To purge the DB at boot, use 'sails lift --drop'